# Trying to Understand the Logic

Tags: algorithm, logic

> Let's consider a triangle of numbers in which a number appears in the first line, two numbers appear in the second line, three in the third line, etc. Develop a program which will compute the largest of the sums of numbers that appear on the paths starting from the top towards the base, so that 
>     on each path the next number is located on the row below, more precisely either directly below or below and one place to the right;
>     the number of rows is strictly positive, but less than 100;
>     all numbers are positive integers between 0 and 99.

**Input** ::
In the first line integer n - the number of test cases (equal to about 1000). Then n test cases follow. Each test case starts with the number of lines which is followed by their content.

**Output** ::
For each test case write the determined value in a separate line.

**Example**

```
Input:
2
3
1
2 1
1 2 3
4 
1 
1 2 
4 1 2
2 3 1 1 

Output:
5
9
```

My Question is How is the output given as 5 and 9?

Comment: How is this related to the C language?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I'm not sure how anyone can help you.

Comment: Well, well, as I see it, this is not write my code request. OP is asking for help to understand the requirement. Please read once more before casting CV.

Comment: @SouravGhosh already fixed, you can delete your comment.

Comment: @MichaelWalz what fixed? I just added that comment for generic purpose, nothing to your comment, it's a very valid one.

Comment: @MichaelWalz also see @ chris's comment.....IMHO, it makes no sense.

Comment: @ChrisTurner No, for this question we don't need code, I think.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I retracted my CV and removed the comment. Because it __is__ not "write my code request"-

Comment: @MichaelWalz Ahh OK, but your first comment is still valid. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh if it's not a query about how some (as yet unseen) code works, is this the right place to ask the question?

Comment: @ChrisTurner OP is asking to understand the requirement, as form of Input and expected O/P. There's no need for code. It is not specific to any code segment, it's the requirement understanding, according to which the code need to be written.

Comment: Hi.. Sorry for the confusion.. I was doing C Programs when I encountered this question so I added the tag for C. 
I am really sorry if it made a lot of confusion. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first output is 5. Let's see, you have the following triangle (since the first line is the number of triangles in the input, 2, and the second line the *height* of the next pyramid, 3):

```
1
2 1
1 2 3
```

You start at the first line and always go either straight down or down+one to the right, summing numbers on the way.

There are many solutions here:

- always down: 1+2+1 = 4
- always right: 1+1+3 = 5
- down, then right: 1+2+2=5
- ...

So the best you can do is 5.

The same logic applies to the second triangle:

```
1 
1 2 
4 1 2
2 3 1 1
```

The best is 1+1+4+3=9, i.e. *down,down,right*.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.
So when I will be writing the code I have to check for all the possibilities, right?
Out of the possibilities which one is the highest that one I have to select, isn't it..??

Comment: That's pretty much it, yes. Or find a way to _prune_ some path to avoid brute force.

Comment: "find a way to prune some path to avoid brute force"

I thought of trying highest number of the two but that won't work in the second case. Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: @DibakarBose There is a way where we do not have to check all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the answer we have to check all the possibilities, but in this approach it is not required.
It works as -

- Start form the penultimate row, and for each element in that row
  check what maximum sum that element could produce and replace the
  element by that maximum.
- The procedure is repeated for the rows above and finally we get the
  maximum value that can be attained by considering the topmost
  element.
  The above approach is dynamic programming approach.
  This solution has complexity  O(number of elements) but if we check all the possibilities then it will give an exponential solution.
  The solution can be reached in the following way -

Consider the input

```
    1
    2 1
    1 2 3
```

Consider the penultimate row - 
Now consider the case that if somehow our path contains the 1<sup>st</sup> element of this row, then the maximum that could be achieve considering that element is - `max(2+1,2+2) = 4` and if somehow our path has the 2<sup>nd</sup> element of this row then the maximum that we could we achieve considering that element is `max(1+2,1+3) = 4`.
Now I modify the triangle as shown -

```
1
4 4
```

Now consider the row just above the previous row (which has only one element)
For this the maximum sum that could be achieved if take `1` in our path is - 
`max(1+4,1+4) = 5`
So for this the answer is 5.

For the second case  -

```
1 
1 2 
4 1 2
2 3 1 1
```

After considering the penultimate row the triangle will look as -

```
1 
1 2 
7 4 3
```

4 - replaced by max(4+2,4+3)
1 - replaced by max(1+3,1+1)
2 - replaced by max(2+1,2+1)

Now for the row above it -

```
1 
8 6
```

Lastly -

```
9
```

So the answer is 9.

Here is the link to a problem same as the above one - https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler018

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the reply...

The solution that you have mentioned is great. But is this Recursive Approach?
If we consider the time complexity for this, is it better than the Brute Force technique?

Comment: @DibakarBose The above approach is not recursive and yes it is better than brute force as we are not trying out all possibilities. As you can see that in each iteration we are only accessing the elements in that row. So the total complexity is O(number of elements in the matrix/triangle). I have implemented the code for the above solution too and it was accepted.

Comment: Oh.. That's great.. I will try to do the code.. Let's see what happens. :)

Many thanks for the help.. :)

Comment: @DibakarBose Did you try to code the approach mentioned in the answer by Derin ?

Comment: One more thing.. I think this is not the best place to ask this but still I want to know..

For good coding, math knowledge is necessary I suppose. So can you suggest what are the topics I should be learning or which topics can help me more...

Comment: @DibakarBose Refer Link - [link](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/mathematics-for-topcoders/) and [link](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/understanding-probabilities/). More can be found on the same sites.

Comment: Thanks @GaurangVyas :)